# SQL PIVOT to generate required output

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the data below:

[image]

I am looking for a query that generates the following output:

[image]

I am experimenting with 'PIVOT', but have not yet achieved the desired outcome.

Comment: check my answer if you have more OwningAgency in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT ReviewType, DER, LEI, NOR, [NOT], LIN
FROM Src
PIVOT (SUM(Total) FOR OwningAgency IN (DER, LEI, NOR, [NOT], LIN)) P
```

Comment: Thanks.  It does work.  +1.  I will mark the answer when the time limit expires.

Answer (score 1):

Simple pivoting:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(Total) FOR OwningAgency IN ([DER],[LEI],[NOR],[NOT],[LIN])
) pvt
```

Another way:

```
SELECT  ReviewType,
        CASE WHEN OwningAgency = 'DER' THEN MAX(Total) END [DER],
        CASE WHEN OwningAgency = 'LEI' THEN MAX(Total) END [LEI],
        CASE WHEN OwningAgency = 'NOR' THEN MAX(Total) END [NOR],
        CASE WHEN OwningAgency = 'NOT' THEN MAX(Total) END [NOT],
        CASE WHEN OwningAgency = 'LIN' THEN MAX(Total) END [LIN]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ReviewType,OwningAgency
```

Comment: Thanks.  Paweł Dyl  just beat you to it.

Comment: I add one more way.

Comment: The cases aspect was useful so +1.

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **dynamic column collection to select PIVOT Data**, because it gives you any new column value added in table, suppose after 2-3 days if **new OwningAgency** say for XYZ added in your table **even that it show your new column in PIVOT** result:

```
CREATE TABLE tblOwningAgency
 (
   OwningAgency  VARCHAR(50),
   ReviewType CHAR(1),
   Total INT
 )  

 INSERT INTO tblOwningAgency VALUES('DER','E',584)
 ,('LEI','S',84)
 ,('NOR','S',28148)
 ,('LIN','S',1261)
 ,('DER','T',6310)
 ,('NOR','T',5527)
 ,('NOT','T',35705)
 ,('LIN','E',606)
 ,('NOT','S',22978)
 ,('LEI','T',4283)
 ,('LIN','T',687)
 ,('LEI','E',431)
 ,('NOR','E',161)
 ,('NOT','E',842)
 ,('DER','S',1937)
 ,('XYZ','S',1937)

DECLARE @OwningAgency AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@Query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @OwningAgency = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(OwningAgency) 
            FROM tblOwningAgency c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @Query = 
'SELECT ReviewType, ' + @OwningAgency + ' from 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tblOwningAgency
) x
pivot 
(
    SUM(Total)
    FOR OwningAgency in (' + @OwningAgency + ')
) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

**@OwningAgency :** It will give you your column list on which you wants to apply SUM

Comment: The dynamic aspect was useful so +1.