# Need a select query to get the output as shown below.?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I Have a SQL Table as shown below,

---

```
| Loc | Date | Id | Sts |
-------------------------
|   Hyd |   15-01-2016  |   1   |   A   |

|   Vjd |   16-01-2016  |   2   |   B   |

|   Viz |   15-01-2016  |   3   |   C   |

|   Hyd |   15-03-2016  |   4   |   A   |

|   Vjd |   15-03-2016  |   5   |   B   |

|   Viz |   15-03-2016  |   6   |   C   |

|   Hyd |   15-03-2016  |   4   |   A   |

|   Vjd |   15-05-2016  |   5   |   B   |

|   Viz |   15-05-2016  |   6   |   C   |
```

---

And i need output like,

---

```
**| Loc | Jan-16    |   Mar-16  |   May-16  |**  
**|-------|A |B |C |A |B |C |A |B |C |**  

----------
|Hyd | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |    
|Vjd | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  
|Viz | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

---

Can anyone help me out please..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Look for `PIVOT` to get A,B and C *side-by side*. Then you can use *conditional aggregation* (`GROUP BY` with `MAX(CASE WHEN...)`) to set groups of *ABCs* *side-by-side*.  What you cannot achieve with a simple query are your *meta captions* `**| Loc | Jan-16    |   Mar-16  |   May-16  |**`

Comment: Try this..From the question you asked previously.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131177/how-to-create-a-sql-query-to-count-items-grouped-and-concatenated-by-date

Comment: I Tried this (Replace # with @)
DECLARE #DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE #ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
  --Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
  SELECT #ColumnName= ISNULL(#ColumnName + ',','')
  + QUOTENAME([Date]) 
  FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT  [Date] FROM [Sample]) AS [Date]  order by [Date]
  --Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic
  SET #DynamicPivotQuery =
  N'SELECT [Loc], ' + #ColumnName + ' 
  FROM [Sample]
  PIVOT(SUM(Count(*))
  FOR [Date] IN (' + #ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
  --Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
  EXEC sp_executesql #DynamicPivotQuery

Answer (score 2):

You will basically need to aggregate based on CASE statements, like this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (loc VARCHAR(3), [date] DATE, id INT, sts CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'Hyd', '20160115', 1, 'A';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'Vjd', '20160116', 2, 'B';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'Viz', '20160115', 3, 'C';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'Hyd', '20160315', 4, 'A';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'Vjd', '20160315', 5, 'B';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'Viz', '20160315', 6, 'C';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'Hyd', '20160315', 4, 'A';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'Vjd', '20160515', 5, 'B';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'Viz', '20160515', 6, 'C';

SELECT
    loc,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([date]) = 2016 AND MONTH([date]) = 1 AND sts = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS Jan_A,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([date]) = 2016 AND MONTH([date]) = 1 AND sts = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS Jan_B,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([date]) = 2016 AND MONTH([date]) = 1 AND sts = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS Jan_C,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([date]) = 2016 AND MONTH([date]) = 3 AND sts = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS Mar_A,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([date]) = 2016 AND MONTH([date]) = 3 AND sts = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS Mar_B,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([date]) = 2016 AND MONTH([date]) = 3 AND sts = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS Mar_C,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([date]) = 2016 AND MONTH([date]) = 5 AND sts = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS May_A,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([date]) = 2016 AND MONTH([date]) = 5 AND sts = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS May_B,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR([date]) = 2016 AND MONTH([date]) = 5 AND sts = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS May_C
FROM
    @table
GROUP BY
    loc;
```

Results:

```
loc Jan_A   Jan_B   Jan_C   Mar_A   Mar_B   Mar_C   May_A   May_B   May_C
Hyd     1       0       0       2       0       0       0       0       0
Viz     0       0       1       0       0       1       0       0       1
Vjd     0       1       0       0       1       0       0       1       0
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, but this has to be done dynamically, all the column names should be dynamic and, what i have given is just a sample data.